# Does Anyone Have Lists.AddWikiPage Examples?

Tags: 2010, web-services, wiki

In SharePoint 2010, Microsoft quietly added a new service called [`AddWikiPage` to the Lists web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists.addwikipage%28v=office.14%29.aspx).  It almost appears that this is still meant as a pre-production service.  I am able to call this web service, and it successfully creates the wiki page, but ALWAYS returns the following response (even with bare-bones `wikiContent`).  Nowhere in my content do I have a `<Values>` or `<Where>` tag, so this must be something server-side.  Here's the full error message.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">The 'Values' start tag on line 1 does not
                  match the end tag of 'Where'. Line 1, position 80.</errorstring>
            </detail>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Does anyone have any examples, or can you provide additional ideas/insights?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When I was experimenting with `AddWikiPage` and kept getting this error message as well. It appears like the function itself works, as it creates the Page on the wiki (as long as the pagename is unique) but still throws an error.

I'm using a `try..catch` now.

```
    try {
      wiki2010endpoint.AddWikiPage("{fd0cf7d4-6f70-455a-9c5c-cf31da1209cc}", "pagename.aspx", content);
    } catch {}
```

Comment: I took a similar approach, but am hoping to find out more information about what is going on.  Glad to hear it is not just me. Thanks.